# html form submitted to phppage not returning values but printing in the page itself

Tags: jquery, ajax, return, echo

I have submitted a form using jquery

using the below format(HTML form)

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $("#form_submit").click(function() {
        $("#RegisterUserForm").trigger('submit'); 
    }); 

    $("#RegisterUserForm").validate({ 
        onkeyup: false, 
        submitHandler: contact_submit 
    });

    $('#verificationcode').attr('value', '');

    function contact_done() { 
        window.location = '/'; 
    }
    function contact_submit() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "thankyou.php",
            data: $("#contact_form").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if (data == "SUCCESS")
                    alert('sucess');    
                else if (data == "BADCODE")
                    alert("The security code you typed was wrong. Please try again.");
                else
                    //alert("Message not sent, please try again. Error data: "+data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

php code is :

```
sendmail(params)
{ 
    echo "SUCCESS";
} 
else 
{      
    echo "BADCODE";
}
```

In an iframe I am submitting the form but it printing the value Success or badcode in the page itself not returning to jquery form

Comment: Are you sure `contact_submit()` is being called in the first place?

Comment: yes the from is being posted and sending mail as well ..but result is displaying on the php page itself not returning (these all happening in an iframe)

Comment: That's what happens if the form is submitted normally, not through AJAX. That's why I wanted you to confirm that the AJAX function is being used. Is this Javascript in the iframe?

Comment: Thanks a lot man .I just put the action url in the form as well that's wrong .if you post thru AJAX

Comment: story still the same problem coming ...even I removed the action parameter from the form .. its action is same now as well

Comment: Leaving out the action just defaults to using the URL of the page containing the form.

Comment: You never answered my question: is the Javascript in the page in the iframe, or is it in the parent page? You can't access child elements as you have in your code.

Comment: javascript in the iframe page(contactus.htm).

Comment: Is validation working properly before the submission?

Comment: Any errors in Javascript console?

Comment: no error at all everything is working fine even it sends the mail . but it displaying the result in the php page not returning to the calling page..so I am not able to validate the captcha . please help me on this its very urgent ..

Comment: Would you please stop emphasizing that it sends the mail. It's obvious why that's happening -- the form is being submitted normally, not through AJAX. I'm not sure why, but repeating that doesn't help us make any progress. Can you put an alert in contact_submit to see if it's being run?

Comment: ok fine I will test it now

Comment: no the alert is not working at all now

Comment: Does it work if you load the page outside the iframe?

Comment: the same problem . even I tested with some simple example that too not returning any thing but the echo the string in the php page .. what could be the reason .?

Comment: Can you give me a link to the page?

Comment: please findhttp://demo.cateringandevents.in/contactusform.htm

Comment: Javascript console reports a syntax error on line 48. You have nothing in your `else` clause because you commented out the `alert("Message not sent")` line.

Comment: I recommend always putting `{}` around all `if` blocks so you don't run into problems when you add and remove lines.

Comment: yes I put all the {} again no sign of respite ..

Comment: Now I get __Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'__ You're not using the jquery-validate.js library, you're using gen_validator4.js, which has a different API.

Comment: let me cancel the validation now .

Comment: THANKS A LOT BARMER NOW ITS WORKING FINE AFTER REMOVING THE VALIDATIONS .HOW TO MAINTAIN THE FORMFIELDS ONCE ERROR REPORTED OF BAD SECURITY CODE IN HTML FORM . OR SHOULD I CONVERT IT TO PHP FILE..

Comment: Sorry, I'm too tired to try to deal with a whole different problem here.

Comment: OK FINE THANKS A LOT TAKE CARE